# jQuery email validation regexp problems

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, email

I'm currently working on my own validation, but I have one small problem.
I can't get email validation to work. I have tried some different expressions, but can't get it to work. Maybe i did something wrong with the layout?

```
var email = $('.email');    
function valemail(){
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(email)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$('#registerform').submit(function() {
    if (valemail()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't do regex email validation beyond a very basic `/[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+/` check. A more complex regex will either reject valid addresses or be so complex that it is unmaintainable, both not useful. Keep it simple. Check mail addresses by trying to send actual mail there.

Comment: I would not write my own validation script when [this plugin is available](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).  However, simply take a look at the [email regex contained within it](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

The the following calls:

```
   $('#registerform').submit(function(){
      if(IsEmail($(this).val())==false){
          //do something validation not satisfied
        }else{
            //do something
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not write my own validation script when [the jQuery Validate plugin is available](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

However, you could simply take a look at the [email regex contained within it](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js) and use that...

```
function email(value) {
    // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
    return /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value);
}
```

```
$('#registerform').submit(function() {
    var result = email($('#myemailfield').val());
    if (result) {
        alert('passed'); // <-- your code if passed
    } else {
        alert('failed'); // <-- your code if failed
    }
});
```

**Simple Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m8baZ/**

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
var email = $('.email');
if (filter.test(email)){
```

`email` is a jQuery object, not the string the user typed.  You need to get the actual string out of the input field and use that with your regex like this:

```
if (filter.test(email.val())){
```